# Groovy: deploying a war file

Tags: exception, grails, war-filedeployment

I have a groovy application running locally on my desktop.
Apparently it runs error free. At least all unit tests I wrote are fulfilled.
I want to deploy the application using a **war** file. For this I use the command

```
grails war
```

in the home directory of the application. When doing this I am getting the following exception:

```
Error executing script War: java.lang.NullPointerException
gant.TargetExecutionException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure4.doCall(Gant.groovy:331)
    at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure6.doCall(Gant.groovy:334)
    at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure6.doCall(Gant.groovy)
    at gant.Gant.withBuildListeners(Gant.groovy:344)
    at gant.Gant.this$2$withBuildListeners(Gant.groovy)
    at gant.Gant$this$2$withBuildListeners.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
    at gant.Gant.dispatch(Gant.groovy:334)
    at gant.Gant.this$2$dispatch(Gant.groovy)
    at gant.Gant.invokeMethod(Gant.groovy)
    at gant.Gant.processTargets(Gant.groovy:495)
    at gant.Gant.processTargets(Gant.groovy:480)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at        _GrailsWar_groovy$_run_closure5_closure25_closure26_closure28.doCall(_GrailsWar_groovy:289)
    at _GrailsWar_groovy$_run_closure5_closure25_closure26_closure28.doCall(_GrailsWar_groovy)
    at _GrailsWar_groovy$_run_closure5_closure25_closure26.doCall(_GrailsWar_groovy:282)
    at _GrailsWar_groovy$_run_closure5_closure25_closure26.doCall(_GrailsWar_groovy)
    at _GrailsWar_groovy$_run_closure5_closure25.doCall(_GrailsWar_groovy:258)
    at _GrailsWar_groovy$_run_closure5.doCall(_GrailsWar_groovy:256)
    at _GrailsWar_groovy$_run_closure4.doCall(_GrailsWar_groovy:239)
    at War$_run_closure1.doCall(War.groovy:38)
    at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure4.doCall(Gant.groovy:324)
    ... 10 more
```

Any hint why?

Thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you'll have to find the source of `Gant.groovy` and see what it's doing on that line. Apparently there is some problem caused by your project's specific configuration (since such a show-stopper bug would have been caught if it always occurred), but the error message does not contain much information.

Alternatively, you could try upgrading Grails to the latest version 1.1.1 if you haven't already.

Comment: The problem has been solved by making an upgrade to 1.1.1
Anyway it should be solvable under 1.1

Comment: I agree; there's probably something unusual (and quite possible easy to fix) in the project's configuration or structure that Gant can't handle. Since it is fixed in 1.1.1, it may even be in Grails' bug database at http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GRAILS